# Error: The specified provisioning profile could not be found

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have gone through all the appropriate steps - I need to upgrade my provisioning profile as I added an additional device...Xamarin Studio tells me:

Error: The specified provisioning profile '0EC3B4F7-5AAF-4F1A-B95E-2D106672BDB9' could not be found

I have updated the provisioning in Xcode is there something special I need to do in Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The .csproj file of my project still referenced the old provisioning profile. I deleted that and now all is well!